# Extracting Metadata using Apache Tika and Storing into HashMap

Tags: java, apache-tika

I am trying to extract metadata using apache tika and then putting into HashMap.. But my code get's only the key not the value of that key.. For Example.. It stores only title(as a key) but not its value, in the same way it store keywords(as a key) but not its value..
 And if i try to see what does **md** contains, its shows this:-

```
Description= title=Wireless Technology & Innovation | Mobile Technology Content-Encoding=UTF-8 Content-Type=text/html; charset=utf-8 Keywords= google-site-verification=AzhlXdqBSdUCRPJRY1evCtp2Ko5r9kxB_f81WffACUc
```

---

```
    private Map<String, String> metaData;

        try {
                    Metadata md = new Metadata();
                    htmlStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlContent.getBytes());
                    String parsedText = tika.parseToString(htmlStream, md);
                    //very unlikely to happen
                    if (text == null){
                        text = parsedText.trim();
                    }
                    processMetaData(md);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    IOUtils.closeQuietly(htmlStream);
                }


        private void processMetaData(Metadata md){
                if ((getMetaData() == null) || (!getMetaData().isEmpty())) {
                    setMetaData(new HashMap<String, String>());
                }
                for (String name : md.names()){
//This below line is not working I guess, it stores only the key.. not the value of that particular key..      
    getMetaData().put(name.toLowerCase(), md.get(name));
                }
            }

        public Map<String, String> getMetaData() {
                return metaData;
            }

            public void setMetaData(Map<String, String> metaData) {
                this.metaData = metaData;
            }
```

Any help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

First up, Tika allows multiple values for a given key. You're better off thinking of it as a `Map<String,List<String>>` rather than a simple `Map<String,String>`

I'd suggest you look at the [Tika Metadata JavaDocs](http://tika.apache.org/0.9/api/org/apache/tika/metadata/Metadata.html). You'll either want to check the `isMultiValued(String key)` method for each one, or just call `getValues(String key)` every time

To get the first value for a given key, `metadata.get(String key)` is the right way to go. Not sure why it isn't working for you

You probably want to play with the Tika App jar, that's the best way to debug things, eg:

```
java -jar tika-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --metadata problem.file
```

That'll let you easily see the metadata your file really contains, then when you know that you can track down where in your code you're doing something wrong